# Two users in different membership DBs can’t use same email address

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Q1 - 
I’ve created two membership databases ( using aspnet_regsql tool ) DB1 and DB2. I then created web applications A1 and A2. A1 uses DB1 to store user credentials, while A2 uses DB2. If the user I created in A1 ( via Asp.Net WAT tool ) uses email DB@gmail.com, then none of the users created in A2 can have the same email address. But that doesn’t make sense since the two apps use different databases for storing user credentials?!

Q2 - 
I’ve noticed when I add new membership provider ( within  section of the web.config file) and then try to add attributes, that Intellisense feature doesn’t work, since it doesn’t display all available attributes for that particular provider. Why is that?

thanx

Answer (score 4):

**A1.** If the membership settings in your web.config for App "A2" are pointing to the "DB1", this makes perfect sense, otherwise, this is not likely. Make sure that the ConnectionStringName property is pointing to "DB2" instead of "DB1"

**A2.** Intellisense would not work for a custom provider unless it is registered in the intellisense schema settings for your visual studio installation.

Here's some information on adding a [Custom XSD for intellisense](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/12/07/501466.aspx)

Comment: A1 - As it turns out it doesn’t prevent you from assigning same email address to two users in different DBs, but it does warn you about it(when focus is on email input field). I mistook that as not allowing it.

Comment: A2 - Why would SqlMembershipProvider be consider a custom provider? Isn’t it a part of Net library?

Comment: Check out this article about web.config intellisense issues: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/02/432077.aspx

Comment: That article will save me lots of troubles for sure, but with regards to SqlMembershipProvider, but even after removing xmln reference intellisense feature still doesn't work. That's probably because SqlMembershipProvider is a custom provider? 
But word "custom provider" suggests provider created by non-Microsoft company, while I assume SqlMembershipProvider is created by Microsoft?!